# Hide/Show table TR based on selected radio button - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html:

```
<input id="source" type="radio" name="source" value="1" />
<input id="source" type="radio" name="source" value="2" checked="" />

<table id="dataList">
  <tr row='12'><td>this is row 12</td></tr>
  <tr row='13'>
     <td>
         <input id="item" type="radio" name="item" value="1" />
         <input id="item" type="radio" name="item" value="2" />
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr row='14'><td>this is row 14</td></tr>
</table>
```

any my jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('input[name=source]').click( function() {
    if(jQuery('input[value=1]').is(':checked')) {
        jQuery('#dataList tr[row=13]').show();

    } else if(jQuery('input[value=2]').is(':checked')) {
        jQuery('#dataList tr[row=13]').hide();
    }
  })
})
```

Supposedly when the page loaded, the tr row='13' will be hide if the radio button id=source with value=2 is checked. but it not happen as expected. Please help me.

Comment: Your inputs share the same ID, remember IDs must be unique.

Comment: Edited a bit your code just to fix markup bugs http://jsbin.com/EXosEkA/1/edit Still, what was the question?

Comment: What is happening?  It seems to work fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/Eudft/

Comment: actually i had solved the problem. but another problem come.. see http://jsfiddle.net/softboxkid/u3gus/4 when i click on the radio button id="item", the show/hide from radio button id="source" doesn't work. please help me

Answer (score 2):

You can try 
`$('tr[row="13"]').hide();` 
right after ng `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` 
since you said 'when the page loaded'.

Comment: actually i had solved the problem. but another problem come.. see http://jsfiddle.net/softboxkid/u3gus/4/  when i click on the radio button id="item", the show/hide from radio button id="source" doesn't work. please help me

Comment: You could change your target. I don't know what its called but this thing `$('TARGET')`.
Since you have 2 inputs that has a value of 1.
See the following,
`<input id="source" type="radio" name="source" value="1" />`
and
`<input id="item" type="radio" name="item" value="1" />`.
It may cause overwriting of commands.

Answer (score 2):

You could change your target. I don't know what its called but this thing $('TARGET').
Since you have 2 inputs that has a value of 1.
See the following,
`<input id="source" type="radio" name="source" value="1" />`
and
`<input id="item" type="radio" name="item" value="1" />`.
It may cause overwriting of commands.